# CephFS meets bonnie++: No space left on device

Tags: ceph

CephFS is evaluated as a distributed filesystem in my lab with bonnie++ in the
following setup:

Virtualbox VMs are used with the following settings:

- RAM: 1024 MiB
- One SATA hard drive for OS: 8 GiB
- One dedicated SATA hard drive for distributed file system for each OSD: 8 GiB
- OS: CentOS 7
- Ceph version:  10.2

Ceph is configured for three (3) replicas, i.e.
three VMs are operated as OSDs:

- node1 hosts ceph-mon, ceph-osd and ceph-mds
- node2 and node3 host ceph-mon and ceph-osd.
- admin node is idle

The client runs bonnie++ on a CephFS mounts.
Somehow,  bonnie++ fails to run through.  Instead,  it exits with the following
error message:

`Writing intelligently...Can't write block.: No space left on device`

See attached screenshot:

[image: screen shot 1]

Funnily enough,  `df -h` reports that 8.7 GiB available disk space.

See next screenshot:

[image: screen shot 2]

Is this normal ceph behaviour?  What do you recommend to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure ceph is writing to the mounted device?

Comment: @Major: Yes,  bonnie++ is started in the folder /mnt/mycephfs/tux and CephFS is mounted on /mnt/mycephfs.  User tux has permission to create files in the folder /mnt/mycephfs/tux.

Comment: I am trying to benchmark oracle cloud container and am stuck on the same error. So did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  Let me know if you have been able to fix this problem.